# Click on submenu using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click on the submenu for the HTML code.

```
<div class="appDiv">
    <div class="hreftheme_AppLinks_sub_links_Li_Megamenu">
        <a onclick="appSubmit('/ultimatixPortalWeb/portlets/applications/redirect.jsp?PARAM=236','236','_blank')" href="#"> Timesheet Entry </a>
        <span id="addTofavImage_236" class="favImage" onclick="" title=""> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i have tried the below possibilities but none of them worked out

1)

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.className("appDiv"))).build().perform();         
driver.findElement(By.className("hreftheme_AppLinks_sub_links_Li_Megamenu")).click();
```

2)

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText(Link name))).click().build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText(str)).click();
```

3)

```
// JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
         //executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webelement for link );
```

4)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='parentGroup_26']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[12]/div/a")).click();
```

and also with absolute xpath but none of them worked out.

Comment: HTML code for the above problem
    <div class="appDiv">
    <div class="hreftheme_AppLinks_sub_links_Li_Megamenu">
    <a onclick="appSubmit('/ultimatixPortalWeb/portlets/applications/redirect.jsp?PARAM=236','236','_blank')" href="#"> Timesheet Entry </a>
    <span id="addTofavImage_236" class="favImage" onclick="" title=""> </span>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: Add the code in your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Sub Menu"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("My Sub Menu Item")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info:can you help find the cssSelector("My Sub Menu Item") for above HTML code

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you because I don't see a menu or sub menu in your code. Did my above code help answer your question if you've already figured this out yourself. (I haven't been near SO for a few days)

Comment: HTML code for the above problem <div class="appDiv"> <div class="hreftheme_AppLinks_sub_links_Li_Megamenu"> <a onclick="appSubmit('/ultimatixPortalWeb/portlets/application‌​s/redirect.jsp?PARAM‌​=236','236','_blank'‌​)" href="#"> Timesheet Entry </a> <span id="addTofavImage_236" class="favImage" onclick="" title=""> </span> </div> </div>

Comment: div id="parentGroup_26" class="hreftheme_AppLinks_sub_links_div_Megamenu" onmouseout="removeParentHighlight('parent_26')" onmouseover="highlightParent('parent_26')" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; left: 490px;">
<div class="megaMenuApps" style="overflow-y: hidden;" tabindex="5000">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="lineSeparator" valign="top">
<div class="subCategories_Div">
<div class="subCategoryName"> Employee Self Services </div>
<div class="appDiv">